# java application trouble on raspbian

Tags: java, device, raspbian

I'm trying to run a java application on my rapsberry but I face some problems when I run this. 
The application is successfully compiling and running, but I have a warning that seems to be the reason why it doesn't work well.

My application uses Telldus devices : The TellStick duo and I should see on the screen my devices and sensors to add them (it works on my computer), but the problem is that the application seems not recognize devices, and it could be caused by this warning :

[ouput in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPvfi.png)

I (think) have understood that it can't find the file libTelldusCore.so, in the linux-arm folder. But after some research, I don't find the linux-arm folder.

Maybe I have did something bad, maybe I have forgotten something, I'm quite beginner with raspberry's systems.

So, if someone could help me, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed telldus-core library?
If you have not, try this, might help:

```
apt-.get install cmake libftdi-dev libconfuse-dev
wget http://download.telldus.se/TellStick/Software/telldus-core/telldus-core-2.1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxf telldus-core-2.1.1.tar.gz
cd telldus-core-2.1.1
cmake .
make
make install
```

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=26386

Comment: Hmm I think I did, because the telldus devices work fine with the Telldus official software, the Telldus Center. Anyway, I'll try it.

Comment: I just did it. I tried to compile and run again the application, but I have the same problem.. :/